# replacing whitespace characters with '\t' string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to replace whitespace characters with '\t' string. The text file looks like this:

```
255 255 255             white
  0   0   0             black
 47  79  79             dark slate gray
 47  79  79             DarkSlateGray
 47  79  79             DarkSlateGrey
105 105 105             dim gray
```

---

My code looks like:

```
import re
with open('rgb.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(re.sub(r'\s+', r'\\t', line))
```

The above code gives:

```
 255\t255\t255\twhite
 \t0\t0\t0\tblack
 \t47\t79\t79\tdark\tslate\tgray
 \t47\t79\t79\tDarkSlateGray
 \t47\t79\t79\tDarkSlateGrey
 105\t105\t105\tdim\tgray
```

However, I only want to replace the whitespaces which are after the first number until the color name. Also not in between the color. The output I want is:

```
 255\t255\t255\twhite
 0\t0\t0\tblack
 47\t79\t79\tdarkslategray
 47\t79\t79\tDarkSlateGray
 47\t79\t79\tDarkSlateGrey
 105\t105\t105\tdimgray
```

Comment: ```\s == [\r\n\t\f\v ]```

Comment: Regex Lookbehind: `(?<=\d)\s+`

Answer (score 2):

You can match whitespace immediately following a digit, which should solve the problem:

```
>>> txt = """255 255 255             white
...   0   0   0             black
...  47  79  79             dark slate gray
...  47  79  79             DarkSlateGray
...  47  79  79             DarkSlateGrey
... 105 105 105             dim gray"""
>>> for line in txt.split('\n'):
...     print(re.sub(r'[0-9]\s+', lambda m:m.group(0)[0]+r'\t', line))
...
255\t255\t255\twhite
  0\t0\t0\tblack
 47\t79\t79\tdark slate gray
 47\t79\t79\tDarkSlateGray
 47\t79\t79\tDarkSlateGrey
105\t105\t105\tdim gray
```

I couldn't find a quick way to just ignore the digit in the replacement, so I just made a lambda instead that takes the digit that was matched and appends a `\t` to it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using nested `re.sub`s:

```
re.sub(r'^[\d\s]+', lambda x: re.sub(r'\s+', '\t', x.group()), line)
```

To get rid of spaces at start use `line.lstrip()` before running the regex:

```
re.sub(r'^[\d\s]+', lambda x: re.sub(r'\s+', '\t', x.group()), line.lstrip())
```

The first `^[\d\s]+` matches all digits and spaces at the start of line and the second `re.sub` replaces whitespace strings with a single tab.

Output (for lines without `.lstrip()`):

```
255\t255\t255\twhite
\t0\t0\t0\tblack
\t47\t79\t79\tdark slate gray
\t47\t79\t79\tDarkSlateGray
\t47\t79\t79\tDarkSlateGrey
105\t105\t105\tdim gray
```

Output (for lines with `.lstrip()`):

```
255\t255\t255\twhite
0\t0\t0\tblack
47\t79\t79\tdark slate gray
47\t79\t79\tDarkSlateGray
47\t79\t79\tDarkSlateGrey
105\t105\t105\tdim gray
```

Comment: They don't want `\t` at the beginning of line.

Comment: @Toto  Oh, then `.lstrip()` should help.  If all spaces on both ends should be removed,  `.strip()` will do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with python to quickly answer accurately in python, but here's javascript showing the regex implementation. If the first three parameters will always be strings of digits, you can use handle it this way.

```js
var input = `255 255 255             white
  0   0   0             black
 47  79  79             dark slate gray
 47  79  79             DarkSlateGray
 47  79  79             DarkSlateGrey
105 105 105             dim gray`

var output = input.replace(/(\d+)\s+/g, '$1\\t')

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Apart the question is about python, this doesn't remove the leading spaces.

Comment: I was answering the ask from the question: "I only want to replace the whitespaces which are after the first number until the color name. Also not in between the color" I also clearly state that my answer is purely a demo of the regex which is non-language specific. This could be written in any language that uses the same style of regex and be just as applicable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two passes:

```
import re
txt = """
255 255 255             white
  0   0   0             black
 47  79  79             dark slate gray
 47  79  79             DarkSlateGray
 47  79  79             DarkSlateGrey
105 105 105             dim gray
"""
for line in txt.split('\n'):
    line = re.sub(r'^\s+', '', line)  # remove leading spaces 
    print(regex.sub(r'(?<![a-zA-Z])(\s+)', r'\\t', line)) # change other spaces by \t when not preceded by a letter
```

**Output:**

```
255\t255\t255\twhite
0\t0\t0\tblack
47\t79\t79\tdark slate gray
47\t79\t79\tDarkSlateGray
47\t79\t79\tDarkSlateGrey
105\t105\t105\tdim gray
```